# QT how to wait for command finishing without blocking gui

Tags: qt, wait

Is it possible to wait for the completion of a method without blocking the gui?

My commandhandler->execute() method works with signals and slots to send a list of single commands to a tcpclient.

When the method is finished it sends a "i'm ready" signal".

After that the second execute should be called. The wait should happen without blocking the gui.

```
void Main::displayCompleted() { 
    m_device->getCommandHandler()->execute(DeviceCommands::UpdateFirmware); 
    WAIT for "i'm ready" signal
    m_device->getCommandHandler()->execute(DeviceCommands::InitializeController);
}
```

Is this possible, if so how would I have to implement it?

Comment: This is commonly done with a separate thread (usually referred to as a "worker thread" in Qt-land. It's hard to be more specific with the amount of code you've shown, but I suspect you'd connect the signal from your execute() method to a slot in the main (GUI) thread to notify the user that the command has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at QThread.  Derive from this, perform the expensive operation in the run() method of derived class,  When the Thread has finished post a signal back to the GUI slot informing the UI the work is complete.

Something along the lines of the following psuedo...

```
class MyThread : public QThread {
Q_OBJECT
    
public:
    MyThread();
    void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        /* perform expensive task here */
    }
};

.
.
.

void MainWindow::startWorkInAThread() {
    MyThread *mythread = new MyThread(this);
//Wire up the thread completion with the UI
    connect(mythread, &MyThread::finished, this, 
 MainWindow::notifyThreadFinished);
//Start the Thread, which initiates the run() method
    mythread->start();    
}
```

Obviously this is just a rough idea of what to do, but hopefully it's enough to get going.

Answer (score 1):

If the `execute()` function is blocking, you have 2 options:

1. Instantiate the command handler on a separate thread and implement the `execute()` like this -> `void CmdHandler::execute() { emit selfExecute(); }`. Then in the constructor of CmdHandler -> `QObject::connect(this, &CmdHandler::selfExecute, this, &CmdHandler::onExecute);` and in onExecute you can run your blocking code and at the end of the function emit a signal to notify your `Main` class. The selfExecute involves a thread switch.
2. Use QtConcurrent to run the `execute()` function in a separate thread. Something like that:

   ```
   void Main::displayCompleted()
   {
     QFutureWatcher<void>* watcher = new QFutureWatcher<void>;
     QObject::connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, this, [watcher]()
     {
       m_device->getCommandHandler()->execute(DeviceCommands::InitializeController);
       watcher->deleteLater();
     });

     QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run([]()
     {
       m_device->getCommandHandler()->execute(DeviceCommands::UpdateFirmware);
     });

     watcher->setFuture(future);
   }
   ```